# Index file - size changed

Tags: sql-server

I realised today that my index file(which is about 250GB) is smaller than yesterday for about 7GB.

Everything, I done in the meantime, was index rebuild.

Is it possible that index rebuild is the reason that file became smaller?

Tnx.

Comment: What is your "index file"? Do you mean data file (.mdf)? The only way the file will get smaller is if someone ran a shrink against it. Do you have `AutoShrink` enabled, or a maintenance plan that includes a shrink database task? If you answer yes to either of those, turn them off immediately.

Comment: Are you sure the sql-server tag is correct? Which DB engine are you using?

Comment: No, I mean .ndf file. 
And I read size of my file in the 'Shrink box' like Available free space. My allocated space was same. SQL Server 2014.

So, no I didnt shrink - alocated space would be changed. Everything I done was index rebuild

Comment: I'm unclear on what metric exactly you're referring to. Disk space usage? Allocated space? Unallocated space? A rebuild can reduce allocated space. it will never shrink a file on disk.

Comment: what else happened yesterday to your database :)?

Comment: Did you rebuilt index with compression option ? Can you show the query?

Comment: Hi, I used this precedure
https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Answer (score 2):

By index file, you mean you place indexes on a dedicated filegroup that maps to the file in question?

Yes, it could indeed be smaller. Indexes can become fragmented over time (inserts and updates need to split pages when inserting into a range) causing free space on your pages over that defined by your fillfactor. If your fillfactor is say 80%, this is not maintained as pages are split, meaning your free space on a page could be 50%. When the index is rebuilt, your pages will be 80% full again, meaning less pages (space) is required for the index as a whole.

Do you mean your physical file reduced in size when viewed in windows explorer? The above describes the space used by an individual index. If your physical file has gone smaller, you must also have a process that shrinks the file to reclaim the lost space (autoshrink on or a job that shrinks?). In general, this is not good practice as your file will only have to grow again as more data is added and your indexes become fragmented again.

Comment: Andy I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. I mean - allocated space. I place indexes on a dedicated filegroup that maps to the file in question. 
My physical file is not reduced in size when viewed in windows explorer. :)

Your first answer is what i need. I was afraid that maybe I  lost some data and needed and I never looked for allocated space until today so I was confused. Thank you!